# Jenkins build fails no error

Tags: windows, eclipse, maven, jenkins

I am quite new when it comes to Jenkins and I am trying to setup a continuous integration environment for our workspace. I am running Jenkins locally on a Windows client - solely for testing purposes - but cannot seem to find the error that is causing the build to fail. All I want to do is trigger an automatic build that will compose the .war file.

Here is the generated output from Jenkins:

```
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\POSIOS\workspace\XudoxWS\src\main\XudoxWS\pom.xml mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XudoxWS WebServer 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.116s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 14 18:22:33 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can confirm that I can locally build the project without any issues. I am using Maven.

Thanks in advance for your offered help.

Comment: try to run the build in Jenkins with -X parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've set the following as goals and options:
`mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`
You shouldn't include the `mvn` executable, then it'll work just fine.

Comment: That was indeed the case, my bad. Wouldn't have noticed it without your help. Thank you for the keen eye! Your help is much appreciated.